# how to wait for 1 ajax call to end for making another ajax call in loop?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am calling a function inside a loop which makes an ajax call.  I need to wait for 1 ajax call to end before making another call.  The code is like-

```
function chkAll(field, markr) {
    var string = "document.forms[0].pCheckBox" + markr + ".checked";
    var temp = eval(string);
    if (temp) {
        if (field.length > 1) {
            for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
                field[i].checked = true;
                decide(field[i].id, field[i].value);
            }
        }
        else {
            field.checked = true;
            decide(field.id, field.value);
        }
    }
}
```

the function that is making the ajax call is the following :

```
function decide(code, dataString) {
    if (document.getElementById(code).checked) {
        var url = "../PRODUCT/PCProcess_Ajax.jsp?CIMS_CSRFTOKEN=" + getTokenFromSessionId();
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        httpRequest.open("POST", url, true);
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        varparameters = "pScreenId=ClmReports&pEventCode=NFACREATE&pDataString=" + 
            dataString + "&pSelectName=" + code;
        httpRequest.send(parameters);
    } else {
        var url = "../PRODUCT/PCProcess_Ajax.jsp?CIMS_CSRFTOKEN=" + getTokenFromSessionId();
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        httpRequest.open("POST", url, true);
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var parameters = "pScreenId=ClmReports&pEventCode=NFADELETE&pDataString=" + dataString;
        httpRequest.send(parameters);
    }
}
```

in `processRequest()` I just store `httpRequest.responseText` and use it.I want to ensure that one `decide()` is called after preveious 1 is finished.

any view in this??

Comment: use jquery, it makes this process very easy

Comment: sorry,cant use jquery.this is a exixting product code.

Answer (score 2):

Use a queueing system. Have an array somewhere that you push on a url/data structure (basically a job queue), as well as a var that flags when an ajax request is outstanding. After you push your todo data onto the array, call a function (doNextAjax()?) which checks the flag's status, and initiates the ajax request if there's no outstanding job. If there is an outstanding job, the function simply returns.

In the success handler of the ajax call, simply call this doNextAjax() function, to initiate the next ajax call.

This should let you simulate synchronous requests without actually tying up the browser the way real synchronous requests do.

---

ok. some sample code. probably won't work, since I'm going off the top of my head, but...

```
var jobQueue = [];
var ajaxActive = false;

function addToQueue(url, data) {
   jobQueue.push({'url' : url, 'data': data});
   doAjax();
}

function doAjax() {
   if (ajaxActive) { return; } // ajax request still outstanding
   if (jobQueue.length = 0) { return; } // no more work to do
   todo = jobQueue.pop();
   ajaxActive = true;
   $.ajax({
      url: todo.url,
      data: todo.data,
      success: function(returnedata) {
          ... do whatever you need with the returned data ...
          ajaxActive = false;
          doAjax(); // schedule another job, if need be.
      },
      error: function(e) {
          ... handle error ...
          ajaxActive = false;
          doAjax(); // schedule next job, if need be
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: I think this gonna work...though i havnt got it completely.. can u please put into a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite this and it will make your logic a bit simpler.  You're trying to mix-and-match synchronous with asynchronous.  If you must make 1 call per checkbox, you should rewrite the code to make a success/failure callback from your xmlhttprequest continue on to the next checkbox.  Since you have the ordinal position of the checkbox, you can continue on to the next ordinal position on success or failure.

To be honest though, your best bet would be to change this into one web request that contains all of the data.  It will make your application appear quicker because it won't have to wait for each checkbox to go through the whole request/response cycle.